# Using Devise and Omniauth, for facebook : Routing Error uninitialized constant OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I'm a newbie on rails, trying to get my login to work using devise gem and Omniauth, facebook from [this tutorial Here](http://willschenk.com/setting-up-devise-with-twitter-and-facebook-and-other-omniauth-schemes-without-email-addresses/) I think the problem is in my routes.rb file but I can't spot it, can you spot it for me?

Here is my routes.rb file

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :requests
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/rabbit', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users, class_name: 'FormUser', :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', 
    registrations: 'registrations'}
  #devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/auth/:provider/upgrade' => 'omniauth_callbacks#upgrade', as: :user_omniauth_upgrade
    get '/users/auth/:provider/setup', :to => 'omniauth_callbacks#setup'
  end


  resources :listings do
    resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index] do
      put "upvote", to: "reviews#upvote"
      put "downvote", to: "reviews#downvote"
      resources :user
    end
  end

  get 'pages/about'

  get 'pages/how'

  get 'pages/faqs'

  get 'pages/contact'

  get 'pages/privacy'

  get 'pages/tos'

  get 'pages/guidelines'

  root 'listings#index'

  resources :notifications do 
    collection do
      post :mark_as_read
    end
  end

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Here is my omniauth_callback_controller.rb

```html
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def instagram
    generic_callback( 'instagram' )
  end

  def facebook
    generic_callback( 'facebook' )
  end

  def twitter
    generic_callback( 'twitter' )
  end

  def google_oauth2
    generic_callback( 'google_oauth2' )
  end

  def generic_callback( provider )
    @identity = Identity.find_for_oauth env["omniauth.auth"]

    @user = @identity.user || current_user
    if @user.nil?
      @user = User.create( email: @identity.email || "" )
      @identity.update_attribute( :user_id, @user.id )
    end

    if @user.email.blank? && @identity.email
      @user.update_attribute( :email, @identity.email)
    end

    if @user.persisted?
      @identity.update_attribute( :user_id, @user.id )
      # This is because we've created the user manually, and Device expects a
      # FormUser class (with the validations)
      @user = FormUser.find @user.id
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: provider.capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Rake routes

[image]

Here is my error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file must be called `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`. Right now, it's called `omniauth_callback_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

i recently added facebook authentication in my app.This is how the code set up is..

my url was - `my-localhost/users/auth/facebook`

```
######in routes
  devise_for :users,:controllers => { 
    :sessions => "users/sessions", 
    :registrations =>  "users/registrations", 
    :passwords =>  "users/passwords",
    :confirmations =>  "users/confirmations",
    omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
  }

####in controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
def facebook 
    logger.tagged("FACEBOOK LOGIN"){ logger.info "=====Login with facebook================"}
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      if @user.persisted?
        sign_in_and_redirect @user ###, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
      else
        session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        flash[:error] = "Unable to login from Facebook because of these errors:"
        flash[:error] << "#{@user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"
        flash[:error] << ".Kindly signup"        
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end

 end


    ####in my user.rb   
    class << self

      ##============for facebook
      def find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
          @facebook_user = where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
            user.provider = auth.provider
            user.uid = auth.uid
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            user.username = auth.info.name
            user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
            user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)    
            ##using Koala gem to fetch address too
            @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(auth.credentials.token,configatron.fb_app_secret)
            ##Check more permissions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2
            user_location = @graph.get_object("me?fields=first_name,last_name,email,location")
          end

          return @facebook_user

      end  

end
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you @milind, I seem to get a new error now "LoadError in OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook
Unable to autoload constant OmniauthCallbacksController, expected /Users/gichuru/Workspace/bubewa/app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb to define it"  - any idea where that is coming from?

Comment: Check the path of the controller...app/controllers/users/ or just app/controllers/ ....verify the same in the controller too.

Comment: in your controller...class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController...this is what it should be...class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

Comment: was that helpful..if yes..kindly accept this answer :)